# Create an embedded picture from a VBA shape inserted by VBA code

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code which allows me to create a free shape. This works fine, however I would like to make sure its an embedded picture (so I can select the whole picture and drag it around.

```
Sub ArrayLoop(array1, array2)
  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1) - 1
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddLine(BeginX:=array1(i), BeginY:=array2(i), EndX:=array1(i + 1), EndY:=array2(i + 1)).Line
      .DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128)
    End With
  Next
End Sub

Sub TestArrayLoop()
  Dim C1, C2
  C1 = Array (848.9067,860.2763,859.5809,849.0524,776.9896,776.9896,776.9896,783.0045,783.4444,777.2606,848.9067)
  C2 = Array(424.4964,387.9998,351.0141,317.205,340.3528,340.3528,340.3528,359.4618,380.6804,401.2172,424.4964)


  ArrayLoop C1, C2  
End Sub
```

Any thought on what I should change here?

Comment: Embedded objects use OLE to place an Excel file or PDF in a presentation. It sounds like you want a grouped shape, not an embedded shape. If these are the only shapes on the slide, you can just add this line to ArrayLoop just before the End Sub statement:   ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range.Group

Comment: Thanks John, appreciated.